# Why can't java 7 use diamond operator and multi-catch statement

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

um using Java 7 (1.7.0_67) and Project language level is set to 7-Diamonds,ARM, multi-catch. My code is as follows, the lines that throw the compilation errors while building using maven.

```
private Map<String, List<InstrumentationClassData>> classMap = new HashMap<>(); //line 36 in InstrumentingAgent
```

Multi-catch block in InstrumentingAgent line 63

```
} catch (InstrumentationException | JAXBException e){
            e.getMessage();
}
```

I am getting following errors when compiling. Why doesn't it work? What am I doing wrong. I am working on IntelliJ IDE.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project instrumentation-agent: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/Documents/instrumentation-agent/src/main/java/org/wso2/das/javaagent/instrumentation/InstrumentingAgent.java:[36,79] error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /home/Documents/instrumentation-agent/src/main/java/org/wso2/das/javaagent/instrumentation/InstrumentingAgent.java:[63,47] error: multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
```

According to what I read diamond operator should work with Java 7. But why am I getting this. If I fill the diamonds with relevant types then the IDE turn them gray and say it could have replaced with diamond operator. But when I replace it gives following errors.

Comment: _um using Java 7_ No, you aren't. You're compiling with 1.5.

Comment: The error message says you're compiling as 1.5. There are various resources out there if you search for how to get maven to compile using java 7, which should fix this for you.

Comment: You're also using an ancient version of the `maven-compiler-plugin`, which suggests you just don't have a plugin configuration at all in your POM.

Comment: I think you are confusing the Java version running in your IDE (what you _see) with the Java version you are using to _build_ (what is giving you the errors).  Just change your build JDK to 7 or later and everything should compile fine.

Comment: thanks for the quick replies. when I add the above section to pom and compile, it worked without any errors.

Comment: Then please add that as answer and accept it. Unanswered question are likely to be read - nor nothing in this case.

Comment: It says i need two days to accept my own answer. And why are you guys down voting my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding following to the pom solved the compilation error,

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```