# Functionality of Specifying Java Compile Version with Maven

Tags: java, maven

First off, I want to admit that my title is hideous. If someone can come up with a more befitting title after hearing my question then deleting this part of the post, feel free to do that.

I recently ran into a compilation error during `mvn clean install` due to a multi-catch exception block. Its complaint `error: multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5`. Pretty straight forward.

Except that my `-mvn version` and `-java version` both show me at `1.8` and in Eclipse under `Java Compiler` it shows `1.8` and the `Java Build Path` shows my `JRE System Library` at `jre1.8.X`.

Ran into this post: [Why can't java 7 use diamond operator and multi-catch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194297/why-cant-java-7-use-diamond-operator-and-multi-catch-statement) and tried that answer. So in the `<build><plugins>` of my pom I inserted:

```
<plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.2</version>
     <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Builds fine now. At a basic level I understand this communicated to the compiler that it should use `Java 1.8`. But how? And why did it seemingly not matter that everything else was set at `1.8` until I put this in my `pom.xml`? It was building just fine before this plugin tag when I didn't have the multi-catch block, so what changed?

Comment: What does echo %JAVA_HOME% print ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Actually had the same thought when troubleshooting before post. It was `Java 8` as well, but M2_HOME was using `Java 7` switched that to 8 as well. So everything was post `Java 6`

Comment: Eclipse settings have not influence on what `mvn` does or what the `mvn` default is, which right now is `1.5`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Java (edit: specifically, Maven in this case, not javac by itself) will compile the code to the oldest "reasonable" compatibility version, which is assumed to be 1.5. So, regardless of what version of Java you are using, the generated *bytecode* will still have version 1.5. You can compile and run 1.5 version bytecode with 1.8 Java, you just can can't do it the other way around.

Of course, a lot of features of Java are backwards compatible, so the code will compile and run just fine until you add some new features (lambdas, diamonds, multi-catch etc.). Then you will have to manually specify the target version.

Comment: Gotchya, good to know. I've seen the plugin I cited before, but never knew what it was doing and why, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to this `maven-compiler-plugin`'s [documentation page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/)

> at present the default source setting is 1.5 and the default target setting is 1.5, independently of the JDK you run Maven with. If you want to change these defaults, you should set source and target

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things to consider:

1. What Java version are you using to compile the sources
2. For what target version are you compiling the sources

The Java version you are using is determined by your $JAVA_HOME environment variable. Maven uses the jdk / jre it finds there, no matter what version it is.

For part 2 it's a bit more tricky: Every JDK is able to compile sources for any version up to it's own. With the target level, you are telling the compiler what the minimum Java version is that will be required to run this code. Source level on the other hand, will tell the compiler what syntax level to allow in the sources.

And of course compilation will not succeed if you select a source or target level that's higher than the level of the jdk / jre you are using.