# Cordova Code Push - multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.6

Tags: java, cordova, code-push

Similar to [multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.6 (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943950/multi-catch-statement-is-not-supported-in-source-1-6-use-source-7-or-higher-t)

I've just installed Code Push and the Cordova code push plugin and I'm getting the error:

```
platforms\android\src\com\microsoft\cordova\CodePush.java:652: error: multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.6
              } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                                              ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
```

I'm running Java 8 on this machine. When I run java -version I get

```
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Where would this be coming from?

I've checked through config.xml and package.json, and searched the folder and I can't find any reference to 1.6..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New release fixed this issue. https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push/releases/tag/v1.11.15

Update your `cordova-plugin-code-push` to `1.11.15` or latest version.